# How to get rid of this multiple comparator methods in Java?

Tags: java

I want to make the comparator for file object as parameterized. (Ex: sort by name, length, size, last modified, file extension). One method with parameterized as sortType.

I don't want different methods as stated in [Sort Array by Date and Size (Files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898662/sort-array-by-date-and-size-files)

```
private void sortByName(File[] files){
  Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File t, File t1) {
        return t.getName().compareTo(t1.getName());
    }
  });
}

private void sortByDate(File[] files){
 Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File t, File t1) {
        return (int) (t.lastModified() - t1.lastModified());
    }
  });
}

private void sortBySize(File[] files){
  Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File t, File t1) {
        return (int) (t.length() - t1.length());
    }
  });
}
```

How to create a method something like sort(String sortType) or sort(Enum sortType) and have only one sorting comparator to do the needful.

Having multiple methods is having maintenance issue and unnecessary boilerplate code.

Thanks.

Comment: I note that each of your methods could have a single (simple) line method body if you use lambda expressions. Is that really so much of a maintenance issue? But yes, you could create an enum where each enum value has a `Comparator<File>` provided in its constructor... have you tried that? What happened?

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you please share a code snippet.

Comment: Note: using subtraction in `comparetTo` is already *dangerous* when comparing `int`, even worse if comparing `long` - due to overflow or underflow, the result sign can be wrong - better use `Long.compare` (or `Integer.compare`) ||| BTW the `Comparator` already has factory methods to create `Comparator` for a given `Supplier` (e.g. `comparingLong`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lambdas, method references here, and the comparing methods of Comparator, one can write:

```
    Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, Comparator.comparing(File::getName));
    Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified));
    Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, Comparator.comparingLong(File::length));
```

This even allows composition of comparators, like reverse order, or first by last modified, then length or such.

```
    Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, Comparator.comparingLong(File::length).reversed());
    Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified)
                                       .thenComparingLong(File::length));
```

For an internal usage this suffices. For an external library API maybe not.

---

***Sorting by file extension:***

```
static final Comparator<File> BY_EXTENSION =
    Comparator.comparing(f -> f.getName().replaceFirst("^(.*?)((\\.[^\\.]*)?)$", "$2"));
Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, BY_EXTENSION);
```

The lambda passed to sort does not need to be a method reference like `File::getName` but can be some function on File.

The `replaceFirst` should only keep the extension, yielding `".txt"` or `""` (no dot in name).

Or if you need the file extension as function:

```
class Foo { // Need some class name.
    public static String getFileExtension(File file) {
        return file.getName()
            .replaceFirst("^(.*?)((\\.[^\\.]*)?)$", "$2");
    }
}

Arrays.sort(Foo::getFileExtension);
```

Again using a method reference, though of a static method, File as parameter instead of as `this`.

Should one use a `Comparator<Path>` instead of `Comparator<File>` - as Path is more general than File -, then be aware that `Path.getName()` returns a `Path`:

```
static final Comparator<Path> BY_EXTENSION =
    Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getName().toString()
        .replaceFirst("^(.*?)((\\.[^\\.]*)?)$", "$2"));
```

---

***In one method:***

```
public static final Comparator<Path> BY_NAME =
    Comparator.comparing(File::getName);
public static final Comparator<Path> BY_MODIFIED =
    Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified);
public static final Comparator<Path> BY_LENGTH =
    Comparator.comparingLong(File::length);
public static final Comparator<Path> BY_EXTENSION =
    Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getName().toString()
        .replaceFirst("^(.*?)((\\.[^\\.]*)?)$", "$2"));
```

Either

```
Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, BY_NAME);
```

or:

```
void sortFiles(File[] files, Comparator<File> comparator) {
    Arrays.sort(files, comparator);
}

sortFiles(listOfFiles, BY_NAME);
```

With Stream:

```
List<File> sortFiles(Stream<File> fileStream, Comparator<File> comparator) {
    return fileStream.sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

File[] fileArray = ...
List<File> fileList = ...
List<File> sorted = sorted(Arrays.stream(fileArray), BY_NAME);
List<File> sorted = sorted(fileList.stream(), BY_NAME);
```

Comment: But how to sort by extension. I want to sort method with file extension as well.

Comment: The above one looks simple and straight forward when compare to other solutions

Comment: I have added sort-by-file-extension. Now introduced a constant, as not as easy for repeated usage.

Comment: Thank you so much. But one more query. Is it possible to move this to a method and return the list or array. If yes, add a code snippet if possible.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want, but added a last goodie.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `enum` that implements `Comparator<File>`, and have each enum type to implement the `compare` method

```
enum FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    ByName {
        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
        }
    },
    ByDate {
        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            return (int) (f1.lastModified() - f2.lastModified());
        }
    },
    BySize {
        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            return (int) (f1.length() - f2.length());
        }
    };

}
```

Below code is the implementation to test

```
public class Lab {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File("/Users/**/Documents");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(listOfFiles,FileComparator.ByDate);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listOfFiles));
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to sort any one of them and not all. Your example has for loop and confusing. Can you please share a code snippet which does one sort by passing the parameter, so that will change it accordingly

Comment: @JavaDeve updated, let me know if it is understandable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the code look more concise with just one `Comparator`. Now with Lambda and Java 13's enhanced switch, you can write `sortBy` as follows:

```java
enum SortType {
    Name, Date, Size
}

void sortBy(SortType type, File[] files) {
    Arrays.sort(files, (t, t1) -> switch (type) {
        case Name -> t.getName().compareTo(t1.getName());
        case Date -> Long.compare(t.lastModified(), t1.lastModified());
        case Size -> Long.compare(t.length(), t1.length());
    });
}
```

But from the view of performance, it would be better to use three independent comparators.

Without lambda and enhanced switch, `sortBy` is written as:

```java
void sortBy(SortType type, File[] files) {
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File t, File t1) {
            switch (type) {
                case Name:
                    return t.getName().compareTo(t1.getName());
                case Date:
                    return Long.compare(t.lastModified(), t1.lastModified());
                case Size:
                    return Long.compare(t.length(), t1.length());
            };
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unreachable!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the full working code to run in my machine? Thanks and it would help beginners as well

Comment: @JavaDeve I've updated my answer.

Comment: But how to sort by extension. I want to sort method with file extension as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to use a Stream:

```java
File[] files = {};

Arrays
    .stream(files)
    .sorted(
        Comparator
            .comparing(File::getName)
            .thenComparing(File::lastModified)
            .thenComparing(File::length)
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it's answering the question that was asked...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this method, you don't need to create enum 
Doing it with strings would be the simplest.

```
public static List shortFiles(String shortType, List files){
    files.sort(new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File t, File t1) {
        int x=0;
        switch (shortType) {
            case "name" ->{x = t.getName().compareTo(t1.getName());}
            case "date" ->{x = Long.compare(t.lastModified(), t1.lastModified());}
            case "size" ->{x = Long.compare(t.length(), t1.length());}
        }
        return x;
    }
});
    return files;
}
```

Additional to that i have created a filter for the file List

```
/* I create a FileFilter for files with a extension diferent of *.tmp or *.TMP */
FileFilter logFilefilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {                
            return !file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".tmp") && file.getName().contains(".")&& file.isFile();
        }
};
```

Then create the file List with the File Filter (optional) specifying the path for the files

```
    /* Specify the Directory which contains the files to short */
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\brdn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp");
    
    if(f.exists()){//execute if the Directory exists
        /* create the files with the FileFilter (optionally) */
        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(f.listFiles(logFilefilter));
    }else
        System.out.println("The directory: " + f.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist");
```

Finally here you a complete example

```
package brdn_company.mavenproject2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Mavenproject2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* I create a FileFilter for files with a extension diferent of *.tmp or *.TMP */
    FileFilter logFilefilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {                
            return !file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".tmp") && file.getName().contains(".")&& file.isFile();
        }
    };
    
    /* Specify the Directory which contains the files to short */
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\brdn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp");
    
    if(f.exists()){//execute if the Directory exists
        /* create the files with the FileFilter (optionally) */
        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(f.listFiles(logFilefilter));
        
        System.out.println("----------------SHORTING BY NAME----------------");
        files = shortFiles("name", files);
        for(File file : files)
                System.out.println(file.getName());

        System.out.println("\n----------------SHORTING BY SIZE----------------");
        files = shortFiles("size", files);
        for(File file : files)
                System.out.format("%-70s size= %d bytes \n",file.getName(), file.length());
        
        System.out.println("\n----------------SHORTING BY DATE----------------");
        files = shortFiles("date", files);
        for(File file : files)
                System.out.format("%-70s Date= %s \n", file.getName(), new SimpleDateFormat("dd'/'MMMM'/'YYYY").format(new Date(file.lastModified())) );
    }else
        System.out.println("The directory: " + f.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist");
}

public static List shortFiles(String shortType, List files){
    files.sort(new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File t, File t1) {
        int x=0;
        switch (shortType) {
            case "name" ->{x = t.getName().compareTo(t1.getName());}
            case "date" ->{x = Long.compare(t.lastModified(), t1.lastModified());}
            case "size" ->{x = Long.compare(t.length(), t1.length());
            case "extension" ->{
                    x = t.getName().contains(".")==t1.getName().contains(".")? t.getName().split("[.]")[1].compareTo(t.getName().split("[.]")[1])
                            : !t.getName().contains(".")?1:
                            -1;}}
        }
        return x;
    }
});
    return files;
}
}
```

Which outputs:

```
----------------SHORTING BY NAME----------------
.ses
DTL-5996-162487191930034982.fxml
DTL-5996-3330347463011941505.fxml
DTL-5996-3504539881087568310.fxml
JavaDeployReg.log
JavaLauncher.log
fallback4142601253054055938.netbeans.pom
fallback8710927843535716668.netbeans.pom
jusched.log
pcsx2-1.6.0-include_standard.exe
sqlite-3.34.0-ffd2f809-64f1-445e-85ce-61dea205401e-sqlitejdbc.dll

----------------SHORTING BY SIZE----------------
.ses                                                                   size= 53 bytes 
fallback4142601253054055938.netbeans.pom                               size= 203 bytes 
fallback8710927843535716668.netbeans.pom                               size= 207 bytes 
JavaDeployReg.log                                                      size= 1943 bytes 
DTL-5996-162487191930034982.fxml                                       size= 4248 bytes 
DTL-5996-3504539881087568310.fxml                                      size= 4248 bytes 
DTL-5996-3330347463011941505.fxml                                      size= 4298 bytes 
JavaLauncher.log                                                       size= 12978 bytes 
pcsx2-1.6.0-include_standard.exe                                       size= 137428 bytes 
jusched.log                                                            size= 623658 bytes 
sqlite-3.34.0-ffd2f809-64f1-445e-85ce-61dea205401e-sqlitejdbc.dll      size= 852992 bytes 

----------------SHORTING BY DATE----------------
pcsx2-1.6.0-include_standard.exe                                       Date= 06/mayo/2020 
sqlite-3.34.0-ffd2f809-64f1-445e-85ce-61dea205401e-sqlitejdbc.dll      Date= 13/abril/2022 
JavaDeployReg.log                                                      Date= 15/abril/2022 
jusched.log                                                            Date= 15/abril/2022 
JavaLauncher.log                                                       Date= 17/abril/2022 
fallback8710927843535716668.netbeans.pom                               Date= 17/abril/2022 
fallback4142601253054055938.netbeans.pom                               Date= 17/abril/2022 
DTL-5996-162487191930034982.fxml                                       Date= 17/abril/2022 
DTL-5996-3504539881087568310.fxml                                      Date= 17/abril/2022 
DTL-5996-3330347463011941505.fxml                                      Date= 17/abril/2022 
.ses                                                                   Date= 19/abril/2022
```

Good luck :) and sorry for the grammar, I'm a Spanish speaker.

Comment: No issues with grammer. You have posted a huge. Is it possible to add for extension as well (sort by file extension)

Comment: @JavaDeve Adding this case in the Swicth case should fix it

Comment: I updated the answer for more information visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/440472/17400037